Finding out which movies are overdue in SQL
I have two tables in SQL:

Movies (Columns: Movie_Name, Date_Movie_Borrowed, Date_Movie_Returned)
Calendar_Ends (Columns: Last_Day_of_Year)

I am trying to accomplish the following task:

For each distinct value of Last_Day_of_Year: identify all movies that are currently borrowed (i.e. Date_Movie_Borrowed <  Last_Day_of_Year ) AND not yet been returned (i.e. Date_Movie_Returned >  Last_Day_of_Year)
Of these movies, find out what percent of them have been borrowed for more than 999 days

As an example, here is some data:
CREATE TABLE Movies (
    Movie_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Date_Movie_Borrowed DATE,
    Date_Movie_Returned DATE,
);

CREATE TABLE Calendar_Ends (
    Last_Day_of_Year DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Calendar_Ends (Last_Day_of_Year) VALUES
('2021-12-31'),
('2020-12-31'),
('2019-12-31'),
('2018-12-31'),
('2022-12-31');

INSERT INTO Movies (Movie_Name, Date_Movie_Borrowed, Date_Movie_Returned) VALUES
('Inception', '2022-01-01', '2023-05-01'),  
('The Matrix', '2021-02-15', '2023-05-15'), 
('Interstellar', '2019-08-10', '2022-02-10'),
('The Dark Knight', '2020-12-15', '2022-09-01'),
('Pulp Fiction', '2021-05-10', '2023-04-30'), 
('The Shawshank Redemption', '2018-11-01', '2021-11-01'), 
('Fight Club', '2019-01-15', '2022-05-15'),
('Forrest Gump', '2020-03-01', '2022-08-01'), 
('The Godfather', '2022-06-01', '2024-05-01'), 
('The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', '2019-10-01', '2022-07-01');

I tried to do this with the following SQL code:
# prepare data in long format
SELECT 
    m.Movie_Name,
    m.Date_Movie_Borrowed,
    m.Date_Movie_Returned,
    c.Last_Day_of_Year,
    CASE
        WHEN m.Date_Movie_Borrowed > c.Last_Day_of_Year THEN 'Not yet borrowed'
        WHEN m.Date_Movie_Returned < c.Last_Day_of_Year THEN 'Already returned'
        ELSE CAST(c.Last_Day_of_Year - m.Date_Movie_Borrowed AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS Status_As_Of_Calendar_End_Date
FROM 
    Calendar_Ends c
JOIN 
    Movies m
ORDER BY 
    c.Last_Day_of_Year, m.Movie_Name;


# calculate percentages
  SELECT 
    c.Last_Day_of_Year,
    COUNT(*) AS Total_Movies_Borrowed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (c.Last_Day_of_Year - m.Date_Movie_Borrowed) > 999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Movies_Borrowed_For_More_Than_999_Days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (c.Last_Day_of_Year - m.Date_Movie_Borrowed) <= 999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Movies_Borrowed_For_Less_Than_999_Days,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN (c.Last_Day_of_Year - m.Date_Movie_Borrowed) > 999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS Percent_Movies_Borrowed_For_More_Than_999_Days
FROM 
    Calendar_Ends c
JOIN 
    Movies m ON m.Date_Movie_Borrowed < c.Last_Day_of_Year AND (m.Date_Movie_Returned IS NULL OR m.Date_Movie_Returned > c.Last_Day_of_Year)
GROUP BY 
    c.Last_Day_of_Year;


 Last_Day_of_Year Total_Movies_Borrowed Movies_Borrowed_For_More_Than_999_Days Movies_Borrowed_For_Less_Than_999_Days Percent_Movies_Borrowed_For_More_Than_999_Days
       2018-12-31                     1                                      0                                      1                                              0
       2019-12-31                     4                                      0                                      4                                              0
       2020-12-31                     6                                      0                                      6                                              0
       2021-12-31                     7                                      1                                      6                                              0
       2022-12-31                     4                                      0                                      4                                              0

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.
How can I do this in SQL?
PS: In R, I am more comfortable and know how to do this.
Here are the datasets:
> dput(Movies)
structure(list(Movie_Name = c("Inception", "The Matrix", "Interstellar", 
"The Dark Knight", "Pulp Fiction", "The Shawshank Redemption", 
"Fight Club", "Forrest Gump", "The Godfather", "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring"
), Date_Movie_Borrowed = structure(c(18993, 18673, 18118, 18611, 
18757, 17836, 17911, 18322, 19144, 18170), class = "Date"), Date_Movie_Returned = structure(c(19478, 
19492, 19033, 19236, 19477, 18932, 19127, 19205, 19844, 19174
), class = "Date"), Days_Borrowed = structure(c(485, 819, 915, 
625, 720, 1096, 1216, 883, 700, 1004), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(Calendar_Ends)
structure(list(Last_Day_of_Year = structure(c(18992, 18627, 18261, 
17896, 19357), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Here is the R code:
filter_movies <- function(last_day) {
    Movies %>%
        mutate(status_as_of_calendar_end_date = case_when(
            Date_Movie_Borrowed > last_day ~ "Not yet borrowed",
            Date_Movie_Returned < last_day ~ "Already returned",
            TRUE ~ as.character(as.numeric(last_day - Date_Movie_Borrowed, units = "days"))
        ),
        calendar_end_date = last_day) %>%
        select(Movie_Name, Date_Movie_Borrowed, Date_Movie_Returned, calendar_end_date, status_as_of_calendar_end_date)
}

borrowed_movies <- lapply(Calendar_Ends$Last_Day_of_Year, filter_movies)

borrowed_movies_df <- do.call(rbind, borrowed_movies)

borrowed_movies_df <- borrowed_movies_df[order(borrowed_movies_df$calendar_end_date), ]

Based on this, we can see the evolution of the movies:
                                       Movie_Name Date_Movie_Borrowed Date_Movie_Returned calendar_end_date status_as_of_calendar_end_date
                                         Inception          2022-01-01          2023-05-01        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                        The Matrix          2021-02-15          2023-05-15        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                      Interstellar          2019-08-10          2022-02-10        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                   The Dark Knight          2020-12-15          2022-09-01        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                      Pulp Fiction          2021-05-10          2023-04-30        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                          The Shawshank Redemption          2018-11-01          2021-11-01        2018-12-31                             60
                                        Fight Club          2019-01-15          2022-05-15        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                      Forrest Gump          2020-03-01          2022-08-01        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                     The Godfather          2022-06-01          2024-05-01        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
 The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring          2019-10-01          2022-07-01        2018-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                         Inception          2022-01-01          2023-05-01        2019-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                        The Matrix          2021-02-15          2023-05-15        2019-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                      Interstellar          2019-08-10          2022-02-10        2019-12-31                            143
                                   The Dark Knight          2020-12-15          2022-09-01        2019-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                      Pulp Fiction          2021-05-10          2023-04-30        2019-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                          The Shawshank Redemption          2018-11-01          2021-11-01        2019-12-31                            425
                                        Fight Club          2019-01-15          2022-05-15        2019-12-31                            350
                                      Forrest Gump          2020-03-01          2022-08-01        2019-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                     The Godfather          2022-06-01          2024-05-01        2019-12-31               Not yet borrowed
 The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring          2019-10-01          2022-07-01        2019-12-31                             91
                                         Inception          2022-01-01          2023-05-01        2020-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                        The Matrix          2021-02-15          2023-05-15        2020-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                      Interstellar          2019-08-10          2022-02-10        2020-12-31                            509
                                   The Dark Knight          2020-12-15          2022-09-01        2020-12-31                             16
                                      Pulp Fiction          2021-05-10          2023-04-30        2020-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                          The Shawshank Redemption          2018-11-01          2021-11-01        2020-12-31                            791
                                        Fight Club          2019-01-15          2022-05-15        2020-12-31                            716
                                      Forrest Gump          2020-03-01          2022-08-01        2020-12-31                            305
                                     The Godfather          2022-06-01          2024-05-01        2020-12-31               Not yet borrowed
 The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring          2019-10-01          2022-07-01        2020-12-31                            457
                                         Inception          2022-01-01          2023-05-01        2021-12-31               Not yet borrowed
                                        The Matrix          2021-02-15          2023-05-15        2021-12-31                            319
                                      Interstellar          2019-08-10          2022-02-10        2021-12-31                            874
                                   The Dark Knight          2020-12-15          2022-09-01        2021-12-31                            381
                                      Pulp Fiction          2021-05-10          2023-04-30        2021-12-31                            235
                          The Shawshank Redemption          2018-11-01          2021-11-01        2021-12-31               Already returned
                                        Fight Club          2019-01-15          2022-05-15        2021-12-31                           1081
                                      Forrest Gump          2020-03-01          2022-08-01        2021-12-31                            670
                                     The Godfather          2022-06-01          2024-05-01        2021-12-31               Not yet borrowed
 The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring          2019-10-01          2022-07-01        2021-12-31                            822
                                         Inception          2022-01-01          2023-05-01        2022-12-31                            364
                                        The Matrix          2021-02-15          2023-05-15        2022-12-31                            684
                                      Interstellar          2019-08-10          2022-02-10        2022-12-31               Already returned
                                   The Dark Knight          2020-12-15          2022-09-01        2022-12-31               Already returned
                                      Pulp Fiction          2021-05-10          2023-04-30        2022-12-31                            600
                          The Shawshank Redemption          2018-11-01          2021-11-01        2022-12-31               Already returned
                                        Fight Club          2019-01-15          2022-05-15        2022-12-31               Already returned
                                      Forrest Gump          2020-03-01          2022-08-01        2022-12-31               Already returned
                                     The Godfather          2022-06-01          2024-05-01        2022-12-31                            213
 The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring          2019-10-01          2022-07-01        2022-12-31               Already returned

From here, I can calculate the percentages myself.

There is a number of problems in your code.

You should use DAYS(date1) - DAYS(date2) to calculate date difference in days between 2 dates instead of date1 - date2. Look at the Date arithmetic topic.
DB2 uses integer division. That is: 2/3*100 == 0 because 2/3 == 0. So, if you need percentage without digits after dot, you may change an order of multiplication and use 100*2/3 == 66, for example. If you need X digits after dot, then use dec(100*2, 31-X)/3. For example, to get 4 digits, use: dec(100*2, 27)/3 == 66,6666. Look at the Decimal arithmetic in SQL topic for more info.

